# Optimize copy paste from clip board in excel macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am extracting html table data from a web page and pasting it into excel sheet, From this sheet I am extracting data into another sheet. The complete macro is taking 40 seconds for an url and among this the below few lines take almost 33-37 seconds. Any help is here is most welcome.

```
       Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
       IE.Navigate strURL1 'Ths is my url
       set doc = IE.Document
       Set tbl = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(6)
       'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
       If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
           clip.Clear
           clip.SetText "<table>" & tbl.innerHTML & "</table>"
           clip.PutInClipboard

           'This is the part which is taking the time
           ws1.Select
           ws1.Range("A1").Select
           ws1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
           'This is the part which is taking the time

           clip.Clear
       End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many rows and columns are there to retrieve? Sometimes a loop can be faster than the clipboard parsing operations but the rows × columns have to be limited.

```
Dim r As Long, c As Long
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate strURL1 'Ths is my url
Set doc = IE.Document
Set tbl = doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")(6)
'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
    For r = 0 To (tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length - 1)
        For c = 0 To (tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")(r).getElementsByTagName("td").Length - 1)
            ws1.Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")(r).getElementsByTagName("td")(c).innerText
        Next c
    Next r
End If
```

I haven;t done much row × row pasting but if you can that would be faster than table cell × table cell.

Comment: For every url I want to retrieve data which will fit into 25 cells in one row. They are distributed in 6 sub nodes out of 15 of the table. I used a switch case based on the identifier of the node and it is way faster now. Thanks for your help.